# 'For' loop: creating a new column which takes into account new data from several csv files

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I would like to automate a process which assigns labels of several files.
Accidentally, someone created many files (csv) that look like as follows:

filename 1: `test_1.csv`

```
Node Target Char1 Var2 Start
1      2     23.1  No    1
1      3     12.4  No    1
1      4     52.1  Yes   1
1      12    14.5  No    1
```

filename 2: `test_2.csv`

```
Node Target Char1 Var2 Start
1      2     23.1  No    1
1      3     12.4  No    1
1      4     52.1  Yes   1
1      12    14.5  No    1
2      1     23.1  No    0
2      41    12.4  Yes   0
3      15    8.2   No    0
3      12    63.1  No    0
```

filename 3: `test_3.csv`

```
Node Target Char1 Var2 Start
1      2     23.1  No    1
1      3     12.4  No    1
1      4     52.1  Yes   1
1      12    14.5  No    1
2      1     23.1  No    0
2      41    12.4  Yes   0
3      15    8.2   No    0
3      12    63.1  No    0
41      2     12.4  Yes   0
15      3     8.2   No    0
15      8     12.2  No    0
12      3     63.1  No    0
```

From what I can see, the csv files are created including data from previous runs.
I would like to add a column which takes into account the dataset where it comes from, without duplicates, i.e., just considering what was added in the next dataset. This would mean, for instance, to have a unique file csv including all data:

filename ALL: `test_all.csv`

```
Node Target Char1 Var2 Start  File
1      2     23.1  No    1      1
1      3     12.4  No    1      1
1      4     52.1  Yes   1      1
1      12    14.5  No    1      1
2      1     23.1  No    0      2
2      41    12.4  Yes   0      2
3      15    8.2   No    0      2
3      12    63.1  No    0      2
41      2     12.4  Yes   0      3
15      3     8.2   No    0      3
15      8     12.2  No    0      3
12      3     63.1  No    0      3
```

I was thinking of calculating the difference between the datasets (in terms of rows) and adding a new column based on that. However, I am doing this one by one, and this will be not doable since I have, for example:

```
test_1.csv, test_2.csv, test_3.csv, ... , test_7.csv
filex_1.csv, filex_2.csv, ..., filex_7.csv
name_1.csv, name_2.csv, ..., name_7.csv
```

and so on.

The suffix `_x` goes from `1` to `7`: the only change would be in the filename (e.g., `filex, test, name,` and many many others).

Can you give me, please, some tips on how to run this in an easier and faster way, for example with a for loop which takes into account the suffix and creates a new column based on new information from each individual file?
I will be happy to provide more information and details, if you need.

Comment: Open all files using pandas.read_csv. For each dataframe add a column specifying its file. Combine the dataframes using one of the available pandas methods  (i.e. `append`). Drop duplicates using pandas' `drop_duplicates` excluding the `File` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing something like this.

```
# Importing libraries.
import os  # Misc OS interfaces.
import pandas as pd  # Data manipulation library.

# Constants.
PATH_DATA_FOLDER = ''  # Specify your data folder location.

# Let's get your filenames and only leave unique ones.
list_files = os.listdir(PATH_DATA_FOLDER)
list_filenames = list(pd.unique([file.split('_')[0] for file in list_files]))
# Now, when we have our filenames, we can loop through them, read files and build dataframes.
for filename in list_filenames:
    # Get list of columns using the first data file available and append the `File` column.
    list_columns = list(pd.read_csv(os.path.join(PATH_DATA_FOLDER, filename + '_1.csv')).columns) + ['ID', 'File']
    # Create a dataframe which we will fill with data from different data files.
    df_final = pd.DataFrame(columns=list_columns)
    # Loop through files of same type (test, filex, name...).
    # Here we will loop through indices from 1 to 7.
    # You might also calculate these values dynamically. 
    for x in range(1, 8):
        # Reading a data file.
        df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(PATH_DATA_FOLDER, filename + '_{}.csv'.format(x)))
        # Filling the `File` column with the file index. 
        df['File'] = x
        # Creating an ID column to track duplicates in different files.
        df['ID'] = range(0, len(df))
        # Appending our final dataframe
        df_final = df_final.append(df)
    # Resseting the dataframe indices.
    # Removing duplicates using the initial columns (without the `File` column).
    df_final = df_final.reset_index(drop=True).drop_duplicates(subset=list_columns[0:-1])
    # Dropping the unused ID column.
    df_final = df_final.drop(['ID'], axis=1)
    # Printing out the dataframe.
    print(df_final)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with `pd.concat` and the `keys`-argument ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#concatenating-objects)).

```py
frames = [df1, df2, ...] # your dataframes
file_names = ['file1', 'file2', ...] # the file names

df = pd.concat(frames, keys=file_names)
```

##### Output

```py
          Node  Target  Char1 Var2  Start
file1 0      1       2   23.1   No      1
      1      1       3   12.4   No      1
      2      1       4   52.1  Yes      1
      3      1      12   14.5   No      1
file2 0      1       2   23.1   No      1
      1      1       3   12.4   No      1
      2      1       4   52.1  Yes      1
      3      1      12   14.5   No      1
      4      2       1   23.1   No      0
      5      2      41   12.4  Yes      0
      6      3      15    8.2   No      0
      7      3      12   63.1   No      0
file3 0      1       2   23.1   No      1
      1      1       3   12.4   No      1
      2      1       4   52.1  Yes      1
      3      1      12   14.5   No      1
      4      2       1   23.1   No      0
      5      2      41   12.4  Yes      0
      6      3      15    8.2   No      0
      7      3      12   63.1   No      0
      8     41       2   12.4  Yes      0
      9     15       3    8.2   No      0
      10    15       8   12.2   No      0
      11    12       3   63.1   No      0
```

To keep duplicates within files, we can temporarily set the level 1 index as column so `drop_duplicates` will only match on cross-file-dupes.

```py
df = df.reset_index(level=1).drop_duplicates()

# get rid of the extra column
df = df.drop('level_1', axis=1)

# Set the file name index as new column
df = df.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'File'})
```

##### Output

```py
     File  Node  Target  Char1 Var2  Start
0   file1     1       2   23.1   No      1
1   file1     1       3   12.4   No      1
2   file1     1       4   52.1  Yes      1
3   file1     1      12   14.5   No      1
4   file2     2       1   23.1   No      0
5   file2     2      41   12.4  Yes      0
6   file2     3      15    8.2   No      0
7   file2     3      12   63.1   No      0
8   file3    41       2   12.4  Yes      0
9   file3    15       3    8.2   No      0
10  file3    15       8   12.2   No      0
11  file3    12       3   63.1   No      0
```

Comment: Thanks fsimonjetz. The final dataset should actually still have duplicates but they should just referred to with the dataset they are come from first (like in the last example, filename ALL). The aim is to keep track on the additional data in each dataset to consider the differences. I was considering pd.concat and two lists, but I have been looking for something to run for each file, just separating the filename and suffix and create that extra column for the difference (i.e., data added). Sorry for the confusion

Comment: I updated the solution so it keeps duplicates within files. This should work as intended.